# Auto redirection in WooCommerce after login based on user meta data

Tags: wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, user-data

I am trying to check if a user meta data is empty or not. If empty, redirect the user to a page, else redirect to the default page.

But my following codes is only redirecting to the default page.

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'ac_my_acct_login_redirect');

function ac_my_acct_login_redirect($redirect_to) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $father = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'fath_name', true ); 
    $update_pro = esc_url(get_permalink('123')); // the page I want for redirection if metadata is empty
    $my_acct = esc_url(get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) )); // default woocommerce my account page

    if(empty($father)){
    $redirect_to = $update_pro;
    }
    else {
    $redirect_to = $my_acct;
    }
    return $redirect_to;
}
```

**meta key** = `fath_name` (*even it has value, still the redirection is not working as intended*). Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code contains some mistakes

- `get_current_user_id()` is not necessary, as `$user` is passed to the callback function
- [get_permalink()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) expects an int (123), not a string ("123")
- Make sure the page ID actually exists

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_login_redirect( $redirect, $user ) {    
    // Get user meta
    $value = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'fath_name', true );

    // Empty
    if ( empty( $value ) ) {
        $redirect = get_permalink( 123 );
    } else {
        // Get the "My account" url
        $redirect = get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) );     
    }
    
    return $redirect;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'filter_woocommerce_login_redirect', 10, 2 );
```